# Git approach for multiple repo's with 99% the same code

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow

We have a project (it's Drupal, but I don't believe this can influence the answer) which we have to deploy to 6 countries. Nothing fancy about that.

But here's the catch. All 6, let's call it "versions", have some slightly different code. Meaning, not all logic, templates, preprocess, database schema's,... have to be applied on all 6 platforms. Therefore, we have 6 separate repositories on BitBucket. But these differences are only the minority. 99% of the code is applicable for all platforms.

In other words, if we have a *general bug*, we need to fix this and manually copy/paste this to the other 5 repo's. If we have a country specific issue/feature request, it's only to be applied on that specific repo.
The time we spend on this and the margin for error are way to hight, so we're looking for a better solution.

What would be your advise in keeping these repo's in sync for the general features and yet *not* in sync for the country-specific code.

Maybe we need to make some deploy script which will sync the repo's in some "after build" hook? Is there some (third-party) tool which you think can help us? 
Or do we simple need to review our git-flow and try to fix it all with just one repo?

Answer (score 2):

You can use git branches for this scenario. I suggest the following branch layout:

- You have a branch which acts as "base" branch.
- all specific "versions" will have their own branches which will be based on this branch.

The basic workflow will go as follows:

- When you have a change for a specific "version" you make that on the specific branch.
- When you have a change for all "versions" you make this change in the "base" branch and merge (or rebase) that to all specific "version" branches.

Comment: Same remaks as for Alberto, does this still match the git flow of pull-requests, features branches,...

Comment: @Michiel Yes and no, you can still use feature branches and pull-requests for merging code into specific "version" branches and the "base" branch. But you'll need to manually merge (or rebase) the "base" branch into the different "version" branches.

Answer (score 1):

An ideia is having a `central` branch that keeps that 99% of common code and, instead of having 6 separate repositories, having 6 branches created from that central branch (let's call these branches `version1`, `version2`, ..., `version6`).

So when you need to fix a bug on the common part, you just need to do the changes on the `central` branch and [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) these changes into each branch for a given version. For example, for `version1`:

```
git checkout version1
git rebase central
```

So you would sync all these branches with changes from the `central` branch in an effortless way (and this process can be easily automated).

Comment: Ok, fair approach. I assume Pull Request, Feature Branches, Hotfixes,... are still applicable then?

Comment: Sure! You can still create branches from each version branch and merge then only with PR, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Specific to Drupal you might consider putting all of your country projects into one large repo with no code duplication.  Use [Drupal's multi-site feature](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base) or a custom module to handle what's loaded in each country.  This is probably the simplest solution.

Otherwise I've solved this problem in one of two ways depending on the project.

My preference, if the project's language and framework makes it possible, is to put the common code into one repo which is included as a package dependency of each final project.  In the case of PHP, composer works perfectly because it'll clone the necessary repos and each library is automatically included in the autoloader.  Each of your country projects would get its own repo and the core would be a dependent package.  There's at least one [template for managing drupal with composer](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project).  This can be a little tricky with Drupal depending on how you write your region-specific code, so this solution might not be ideal.  You can always add scripts to the composer install to move files around if necessary, such as dropping a country-specific module into the Drupal module's subdirectory.

Another solution which is guaranteed to work is using git submodules.  Again the common code goes into one repo and each country-specific project gets their own.  The common code is pulled into a directory as a submodule.  In this case the complexity is all about how you organize your code and directory structure.

Comment: So, this will result in 6 repo's (nothing new there), but only the common repo will be build on the 6 platforms? And this build process will include the country specific repo's as a submodule?

Comment: For the submodule approach I would have the country-specific repos contain one submodule referencing the common code repo.  This way you can manage each country's specific merges and deployment process independently if you choose to.  You could also use no submodules and have a simple build script pull each country's deployment code together. This is only necessary if having one submodule directory doesn't work well with Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest merging everything in a single repo and creating several branches for different releases. This way you can easily bring changes to all branches by merge (or rebase, as you prefer). You can even automate this with some script.